# Column width property on hidden columns

Tags: excel, vba

Where is a hidden column storing its columnwidth value?

I've already found out that `testRange1.ColumnWidth = 0`
is the same as `testRange2.EntireColumn.Hidden = True`.
And grouping is similar too:

```
testRange3.Columns.Group
ActiveWorksheet.Outline.ShowLevels columnlevels:=1
```

The result in all three cases is:

```
debug.Print testRange1.ColumnWidth
 0 
debug.Print testRange2.ColumnWidth
 0 
debug.Print testRange3.ColumnWidth
 0
```

Unhiding the columns or expanding the group restores the original `ColumnWidth` (Much to my dismay).

But now i'm really curious as to where those hidden columns store the width to which they will be restored.
Setting the width to something obvious bevore hiding the column and then searching through the properties in the debug window, i couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: `.previous.width`

Comment: Thank you!
Although this isn't quite the correct answer, you led me to it:
`testRange1.Previous.ColumnWidth` it is.

If you post it as an answer, i can accept it and close the question.

Comment: `But now i'm really curious as to where those hidden columns store the width to which they will be restored.` Your question is where is the value **Stored**. I answered that. The value is **not** stored in `testRange1.Previous.ColumnWidth`.  That piece of code that you gave **retrieves** the value stored :)

Comment: I understand, thanks for clarifying :)
That's what happens when an engineer tries to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.previous.width` properties of the range, so

`set r=range("a1")
debug.? r.previous.width`

Would show.

Comment: Warning: this A is **wrong**. [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.previous) - "On an unprotected sheet, this property always returns the cell immediately to the left of the specified cell."

Answer (score 2):

`But now i'm really curious as to where those hidden columns store the width to which they will be restored.`

They are stored in the xml file which can be accessed by renaming the .xlsx file to .zip and then going to the sheet.xml in the `xl\worksheets\` folder inside the zip file

Let's do a small test. Create a blank excel file. And then change the width of the 1st column to 1.22(18 pixels). Change the 4th column's width to 5.89(60 pixels).

[image]

Save the file as say `C:\book1.xlsx`.

Rename the file from `book1.xlsx` to `book1.zip` and open it say in Winzip (*I am using winzip. You can use any other program*). Go to `xl\worksheets\` folder as shown below

[image]

If you open the xml file you will notice the widths stored there for the 1st and 4th column.

[image]

**Another test**

Rename the file back to xlsx. Now hide column A:F. as shown below

[image]

Now see what the xml file has :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I didn't know that you can look into excel files this way.  

But @Nathan_Sav's answer is what i actually looked for.

Comment: No worries :) Feel free to go with that answer.