# Hiding excel columns misreports widths

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to get the widths of columns (hidden and visible) in Excel using VBA.

I want to total the widths of columns between two points and I have to take in to account the widths of hidden columns too which I can do using the `previouswidth` property.

The trouble is that when more than two are hidden, it looks like the `previouswidth` property of one of them is misreported as 0.

The test code I have is:

```
Sub LeftPositionFromCell()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l As Double
    
    Set rng = Range("J2")
    i = 0
    l = 0
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Column
        If (ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Hidden) Then
            l = l + ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Previous.Width
            Debug.Print "address: " & ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Address & " width: " & ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Previous.Width & " (hidden)"
        Else
            l = l + ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Width
            Debug.Print "address: " & ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Address & " width: " & ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Width
        End If
    Next
    
    Debug.Print " address: " & rng.Address & " left: " & l
    Debug.Print

End Sub
```

and sample output for when columns H & I are hidden is:

```
address: $A:$A width: 48
address: $B:$B width: 48
address: $C:$C width: 48
address: $D:$D width: 48
address: $E:$E width: 48
address: $F:$F width: 48
address: $G:$G width: 48
address: $H:$H width: 48 (hidden)
address: $I:$I width: 0 (hidden)
address: $J:$J width: 48
 address: $J$2 left: 432
```

Seems this only happens when the hidden columns are sequential as non-sequential hidden columns report the `previouswidth` correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [`previouswidth` isn't what you think it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.previous)  note, you are actually using  the Width property of `Range.Previous`

Comment: For a solution, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59378459/445425)